# Recyclerview Item Decoration: Draw only on specific rows

Tags: android

I want to draw a white background on my recyclerview rows of first and tenth. I am doing this with Recyclerview ItemDecorator class. But as I scroll the recyclerview , for example , recyclerview.getChildAt(0) returns the first visible row instead of the real first row and this results in a drawing I don't want.

```
public class MyDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private Paint mPaint;

public MyDecorator(){
    mPaint=new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onDraw(c, parent, state);

    View view0 =parent.getChildAt(0);
    View view2=parent.getChildAt(9);

    Rect rect=new Rect();
    rect.top=view0.getTop();
    rect.left=view0.getLeft();
    rect.right=view0.getRight();
    rect.bottom=view2.getBottom();

    c.drawRect(rect,mPaint);

}
}
```

Comment: Think about this again… who knows about the data, drives, and provides information to your RecyclerView? Which entity is aware of where/how to produce and bind views for each row? The RecyclerView knows how to handle a lot of things, but it expects an adapter to supply the data, the view inflation, and so forth. Perhaps… if you look at your adapter, you can provide the logic to tell each view whether it should have the decoration or not.

Comment: above is an example and can be accomplished in an adapter. For the actual drawing in my mind , ItemDecorator has to be used